# How to add CSS to Google Chart's Table without entering a value

Tags: html, css, charts, google-visualization

I have a Google Chart Table that is already populated with Data. I just want to add in colours for each column.

Right now I have:

`dataTable.setCell(1,1,{'style': 'background-color: red;'})`

But this breaks the chart.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`dataTable.setCell` is used for setting a lot of things, I would instead use `dataTable.setProperty`.

`data.setProperty(1,1,'style','background-color:red')` gives you the desired effect, and don't forget that you need to allowHTML in your options with `options = {allowHtml:true};`

[Link to JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/nejx7fd9/) where you can see how.